# package required for "mmetric" function in R

Tags: r, naivebayes

I'm trying out Naive Bayes classification using stock dataset in R.  Now for displaying the final results I've seen a function `mmetric` taking testing data and prediction model as arguments. But while I'm trying the same I'm facing the error could not find function "**mmetric**". I have installed the `rminer` and list packages which are quotes as reference packages for these. But still I could not resolve it.

Any Suggestions to resolve the error?

Comment: @Dave2e no need to comment the changes - you can do that in the window when you are actually editing.

Comment: Please show the code you're using. Are you loading the `rminer` package (`library(rminer)`)?

Comment: do we have are resolution on this problem. it seems i am having a problem also

Answer (score 0):

I got same error but i updated my Rcpp package that will be needed by rminer to load on the system, hope this helps.